# Why is the Audit Logout event for EF5, taking ~3 seconds for EF5?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, .net-4.5

I am trying to put together a prof of concept for changing our home grown ORM solution to EntityFramework 5, and the first problem I run into appears to be a serious show stopper.

EF5 appears, our of the box, to take ~9x longer to execute a scalar sql operation than ad hock sql, BUT when I look at the sql code generated, the sql itself appears to be reasonably well written, and runs quickly.

My C# code for both:

```
 int surveyId = (from survey in upsEntities.Surveys where !survey.Deleted select survey.SurveyID).First();
            Debug.WriteLine("Loading surveyId : {0} through Linq took {1}ms using EF5", surveyId,
                            sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

            sw.Restart();

            string sql = "Select top 1 surveyId from Survey where deleted = 0";
            object val = SMSDataManager.Instance.DataAccessManager.ExecuteScalar(sql);

            Debug.WriteLine("Loading surveyId : {0} through AdHock SQL took {1}ms using OrmDataManager", val,
                           sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

SQL Output:
EF5:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[SurveyID] AS [SurveyID]
FROM [dbo].[Survey] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Deleted] <> cast(1 as bit)
```

Adhock: `Select top 1 surveyId from Survey where deleted = 0`

> Loading surveyId : 1 through Linq took **2965.8625ms using EF5**
>
> Loading surveyId : 1 through **AdHock SQL took 384.8073ms**

The duration between the two, according to the profiler is 1ms for EF5, vs 0ms for ad hock. Where the problem appears to lie is in the **Audit Logout** event **for EF5, taking ~3 seconds,** where my **ad hock sql is taking ~.6 seconds** for the same logout event.

What is causing this huge overhead for EF5, and what can I do to mitigate, or explain this?

Comment: Is the Linq query is the first query on the context? What you are observing may be a result of some initialization that is happening when the first query is run.

Comment: It is the first in the context, and if I replicate the query 2 more times, I notice that the next two are lightning fast, on the order of 15ms.  However, 3 full seconds each time I initialize a context, strikes me as a very long time. My ad hock query spins up a new connection, and that is still below 500ms.

Comment: The initialization happens only once per app domain. Depending on how complicated the model is and how long it takes to connect to the database for the first time it may take a bit. You may take a look at this comment on my blog that discusses the initialization http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/#comment-249. Also this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx is something you may want to look at.

Comment: Can you put this in the form of an answer so I can give you credit? Your last comment effectively answered my question. "Once per app domain"... and I modified my unit tests to show prove that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization happens only once per app domain. Depending on how complicated the model is and how long it takes to connect to the database for the first time it may take a bit. You may take a look at this comment on my blog that briefly discusses the initialization [Entity Framework Code First View Generation Templates On Visual Studio Code Gallery - Comment #249](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/#comment-249). Also this page: [Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) is something you may want to look at.